# yii user and rights module multi-language

Tags: php, yii, multilingual, yii-modules

You can use `yii`'s `users` and `Rights` modules for user management purposes. they have implemented `RBAC` and many features.

they both have implemented for multi-language purposes. So, they have a `messages` folder under their directory hierarchy:

```
modules
--user
----...
----messages
------de
------el
------es
------fi
----...
--rights
----...
----messages
------de
------el
------es
------fi
----...
```

They haven't included all of the languages. If you have customized them for your own language, please share it.

Comment: Language translations is under messages catalog, not under models. You are not using MVC structure. Plus not related to coding, get some people to translate from English to other languages.

Comment: @Justinas it is under `modules`, not `models`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote for persian (fa_ir). change your app language to `fa_ir`, place the following codes under `messages` folder and enjoy it.

### --protected/modules/user/messages/fa_ir/user.php:

```
<?php
return array(
'Registration' => 'ثبت نام',
'Register' => 'ثبت نام',
'Login' => 'ورود',
'Logout' => 'خروج',
'username' => 'نام کاربری',
'username or email' => 'نام کاربری یا ایمیل',
'password' => 'رمز عبور',
'Remember me next time' => 'مرا در این رایانه به یاد داشته باش.',
'Username is incorrect.' => 'نام کاربری اشتباه است',
'Email is incorrect.' => 'ایمیل اشتباه است.',
'This user\'s name already exists.' => 'نام کاربر قبلا ثبت شده است.',
'This user\'s email address already exists.' => 'ایمیل کاربر قبلا ثبت شده است.',
'You registered from {site_name}' => 'شما از سایت  {site_name} ثبت نام کردید.',
'Please activate you account go to {activation_url}' => 'لطفا حساب کاربری خود را فعال کنید. برو به {activation_url}',
'You account is not activated.' => 'حساب کاربری شما فعال نیست',
'You account is blocked.' => 'حساب کاربری شما مسدود شده است.',
'Password is incorrect.' => 'رمز عبور اشتباه است.',
'E-mail' => 'رایانامه',
'Verification Code' => 'Verification Code',
'Retype Password' => 'تکرار رمز عبور',
'Retype Password is incorrect.' => 'تکرار رمز عبور اشتباه است.',
'Incorrect password (minimal length 4 symbols).' => 'رمز عبور اشتباه است. حداقل 4 رقم.',
'Incorrect username (length between 3 and 20 characters).' => 'نام کاربری باید بین 3 تا 20 حرف باشد.',
'Incorrect symbol\'s. (A-z0-9)' => 'حرف اشتباه وارد کرده اید. حرف و عدد پذیرفته می شود.',
'Variable name may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.'=>'اسم متغیر باید از حرف و رقم و خط زیر تشکیل شده باشد و با حرف شروع شود.',
"Length of ' + n + ' must be between '+min+' and '+max+'."=>"Length of ' + n + ' must be between '+min+' and '+max+'.",
'Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.' => 'لطفا حروف را مطابق تصویر وارد نمایید.',
'Letters are not case-sensitive.' => 'نسبت به حروف بزرگ و کوچک حساس نیست.',
'Minimal password length 4 symbols.' => 'حداقل تعداد حروف رمز عبور 4 تاست.',
'Lost Password?' => 'فراموشی رمز عبور',
'Profile' => 'پروفایل',
'activation key' => 'کلید فعال سازی',
'User activation' => 'فعال سازی کاربر',
'You account is active.' => 'حساب کاربری شما فعال است',
'You account is activated.' => 'حساب کاربری شما فعال می شود.',
'Incorrect activation URL.' => 'مسیر وارد شده برای فعال سازی صحیح نیست.',
'Registration date' => 'تاریخ ثبت',
'Last visit' => 'آخرین بازدید',
'Superuser' => 'مدیر',
'Status' => 'وضعیت',
'Ok' => 'خب',
'Show all'=> 'نمایش همه',
'Save' => 'ذخیره',
'Cancel'=> 'انصراف',
'New password is saved.' => 'رمز عبور جدید ذخیره شد.',
'Change password' => 'تغییر رمز عبور',
'Your profile' => 'پروفایل شما',
'Thank you for your registration. Please check your email or login.' => 'با تشکر از ثبت نام شما، لطفا ایمیل خود را بررسی نمایید یا وارد سایت شوید.',
'Thank you for your registration. Please check your email.' => 'با تشکر از ثبت نام شما، لطفا ایمیل خود را بررسی نمایید.',
'Please check your email. An instructions was sent to your email address.' => 'لطفا ایمیل خود را چک کنید. یک دستورالعمل به ایمیل شما فرستاده شد.',
'Thank you for your registration. Please {{login}}.' =>  'با تشکر از ثبت نام شما لطفا {{login}}.',
'Thank you for your registration. Contact Admin to activate your account.' =>  'با تشکر از ثبت نام شما. از مدیر سیستم بخواهید حساب کاربری شما را فعال کند.',
'Restore' => 'Restore',
'Please enter your login or email addres.' => 'لطفا نام کاربری یا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید.',
'Incorrect recovery link.' => 'لینک ریکاوری اشتباه است.',
'Already exists.' => 'قبلا ثبت شده است.',
'First Name' => 'نام',
'Last Name' => 'نام خانوادگی',
'No' => 'خیر',
'Yes' => 'بله',
'Yes and show on registration form' => 'بله، در فرم ثبت نام هم نمایش داده شود.',
'No, but show on registration form' => 'خیر، ولی در فرم ثبت نام نمایش داده شود.',
'Not active' => 'غیر فعال',
'Active' => 'فعال',
'Banned' => 'محدود',
'Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:' => 'لطفا فرم زیر با کامل کنید:',
'Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.' => 'فیلدهای مشخص شده با <span class="required">*</span> الزامی است.',
'List User' => 'لیست کاربران',
'Edit' => 'ویرایش',
'Edit profile' => 'ویرایش پروفایل',
'Create User' => 'ایجاد کاربر جدید',
'Create' => 'ایجاد',
'Manage' => 'مدیریت',
'Manage Users' => 'مدیریت کاربران',
'Users' => 'کاربران',
'Update User' => 'به روزرسانی کاربر',
'Delete User' => 'حذف کاربر',
'Delete file' => 'حذف فایل',
'View User' => 'مشاهده ی کاربر',
'Are you sure to delete this item?' => 'آیا برای حذف اینها مطمئن هستید؟',
'Changes is saved.' => 'تغییرات ذخیره شد.',
'Manage Profile Field' => 'مدیریت فیلد پروفایل',
'Variable name' => 'نام متغیر',
'Title' => 'عنوان',
'Field Type' => 'نوع فیلد',
'Field Size' => 'اندازه فیلد',
'Field Size min' => 'حداقل اندازه فیلد',
'Required' => 'الزامی',
'Match' => 'تطابق',
'Range' => 'محدوده',
'Error Message' => 'پیغام خطا',
'Other Validator' => 'ارزیاب دیگر',
'JSON string (example: {example}).' => 'رشته Json، مثل: {example}.',
'Default' => 'پیش فرض',
'Position' => 'مکان',
'Visible' => 'قابل مشاهده',
'Registered users' => 'کاربران ثبت نام کرده',
'For all' => 'برای همه',
'Only owner' => 'فقط صاحب',
'Hidden' => 'پنهان',
'Profile Fields' => 'فیلدهای پروفایل',
'View Profile Field #' => 'مشاهده فیلد پروفایل#',
'Manage Profile Fields' => 'مدیریت فیلدهای پروفایل',
'Create Profile Field' => 'ایجاد فیلد پروفایل',
'List Profile Field' => 'لیست فیلدهای پروفایل',
'View Profile Field' => 'مشاهده فیلد پروفایل',
'Delete Profile Field' => 'حذف فیلد پروفایل',
'Update Profile Field' => 'به روزرسانی فیلد پروفایل',
'Widget'=>'ویجت',
'Widget parametrs'=>'پارامترهای ویجت',
'Widget name.'=>'نام ویجت.',
'Allowed lowercase letters and digits.' => 'حروف کوچک و رقم مجاز است.',
'Field name on the language of "sourceLanguage".' => 'نام فیلد در زبان "SourceLanguage".',
'Field type column in the database.' => 'نوع ستون فیلد در پایگاه داده.',
'Field size column in the database.' => 'اندازه ستون فیلد در پایگاه داده.',
'The minimum value of the field (form validator).' => 'مقدار حداقل فیلد در ارزیابی فرم.',
'Required field (form validator).' => 'فیلد الزامی در ارزیابی فرم.',
"Regular expression (example: '/^[A-Za-z0-9\s,]+$/u')." => "عبارت منظم، مثل: '/^[A-Za-z0-9\s,]+$/u'.",
'Predefined values (example: 1;2;3;4;5 or 1==One;2==Two;3==Three;4==Four;5==Five).' => 'Predefined values (example: 1;2;3;4;5 or 1==One;2==Two;3==Three;4==Four;5==Five).',
'Error message when you validate the form.' => 'پیغام خطا هنگام ارزیابی فرم.',
'The value of the default field (database).' => 'مقدا فیلد پیشفرض در پایگاه داده',
'Display order of fields.' => 'نمایش ترتیب فیلدها',
'Not visited' => 'مشاهده نشده',
);
```

### --modules/rights/messages/fa_ir/core.php:

```
<?php


return array(
'A descriptive name for this item.' => 'یک عبارت توضیحی برای این عنصر',
'A role is group of permissions to perform a variety of tasks and operations, for example the authenticated user.' => 'یک نقش، دربردارنده ی گروهی از مجوزها برای انجام تکلیف ها و عمل های متعدد است.',
'A task is a permission to perform multiple operations, for example accessing a group of controller action.' => 'تکلیف، مجوزی است برای انجام چند عمل، برای مثال دسترسی به گروهی از controller actionها',
'Additional data available when executing the business rule.' => 'هنگام اجرای قانون، داده های بیشتری موجود خواهد بود.',
'An operation is a permission to perform a single operation, for example accessing a certain controller action.' => 'یک عمل، مجوزی است برای انجام یک عمل تنها، مثلا دسترسی به یک controller action خاص.',
'Are you sure you want to delete this operation?' => 'آیا نسبت به حذف این عمل اطمینان دارید؟',
'Are you sure you want to delete this role?' => 'آیا اطمینان به حذف این نقش دارید؟',
'Are you sure you want to delete this task?' => 'آیا اطمینان به حذف این تکلیف دارید؟',
'Assign item' => 'تخصیص عنصر',
'Authorization item' => 'عنصر دسترسی',
'Authorization items can be managed under {roleLink}, {taskLink} and {operationLink}.' => 'برای مدیریت عناصر تصدیق هویت به {roleLink}, {taskLink} و {operationLink} مراجعه کنید.',
'Business rule cannot be empty.' => 'قانون نمی تواند خالی باشد.',
'Cancel' => 'انصراف',
'Code that will be executed when performing access checking.' => 'کدی که هنگام بررسی سطح دسترسی اجرا می شود.',
'Do not change the name unless you know what you are doing.' => 'نام ها را بی جهت تغییر ندهید. مگر اینکه به انجام این کار آگاه باشید.',
'Generate items' => 'تولید عناصر',
'Generate items for controller actions' => 'تولید عناصر برای  Controller actions',
'Here you can view and manage the permissions assigned to each role.' => 'در این قسمت می توانید مجوزهای تخصیص یافته به هر نقش را مشاهده و مدیریت کنید.',
'Here you can view which permissions has been assigned to each user.' => 'در این قسمت می توانید ببینید که به هر کاربر چه مجوزهایی تخصیص یافته است.',
'Item' => 'عنصر',
'Name of the superuser cannot be changed.' => 'نام کاربر ویژه قابل تغییر نیست.',
'No actions found.' => 'هیچ اکشنی یافت نشد.',
'No assignments available to be assigned to this user.' => 'هیچ تخصیصی برای این کاربر یافت نشد.',
'No children available to be added to this item.' => 'هیچ فرزندی برای اضافه کردن به این عنصر وجود ندارد.',
'Operations exist below tasks in the authorization hierarchy and can therefore only inherit from other operations.' => 'در سلسه مراتب تصدیق هویت، عمل ها زیر تکلیف ها قرار می گیرند. لذا هر عمل فقط می تواند از عمل های دیگر ارث بری کند.',
'Permission :name assigned.' => 'مجوز :name تخصیص یافت.',
'Permission :name revoked.' => 'مجوز :name صلب شد.',
'Please select which items you wish to generate.' => 'لطفا عناصری را می خوهید تولید شوند انتخاب کنید.',
'Roles exist at the top of the authorization hierarchy and can therefore inherit from other roles, tasks and/or operations.' => 'نقش ها در بالای سلسله مراتب تصدیق هویت قرار می گیرند. لذا از نقشها و تکلیف ها و عمل ها می توانند ارث بری کنند.',
'Source' => 'منبع',
'Tasks exist below roles in the authorization hierarchy and can therefore only inherit from other tasks and/or operations.' => 'تکلیف ها در سلسله مراتب تصدیق هویت زیر نقش ها قرار می گیرند. لذا فقط می توانند از تکلیف ها و عمل ها ارث بری کنند.',
'There must be at least one superuser!' => 'حداقل باید یک کاربرویژه (superuser) وجود داشته باشد.',
'This user has not been assigned any items.' => 'هیچ عنصری به این کاربر تخصیص نیافته است.',
'Type' => 'نوع',
'Update :name' => 'تغییر :name',
':name created.' => ':name ایجاد شد.',
':name deleted.' => ':name حذف شد.',
':name updated.' => ':name تغییر یافت.',
'Add' => 'اضافه کردن',
'Add Child' => 'اضافه کردن فرزند',
'An item with this name already exists.' => 'عنصری با این نام قبلا ثبت شده است.',
'Application' => 'برنامه',
'Assign' => 'تخصیص',
'Assignments' => 'تخصیص یافته ها',
'Assignments for :username' => 'تخصیص یافته ها به :username',
'Authorization items created.' => 'عناصر تصدیق هویت ایجاد شد.',
'Business rule' => 'قانون',
'Child :name added.' => 'فرزند با عنوان :name اضافه شد',
'Child :name removed.' => 'فرزند با عنوان :name حذف شد.',
'Children' => 'فرزندان',
'Create :type' => 'ایجاد :type',
'Create a new operation' => 'ایجاد عمل جدید',
'Create a new role' => 'ایجاد نقش جدید',
'Create a new task' => 'ایجاد تکلیف جدید',
'Data' => 'تاریخ',
'Delete' => 'حذف',
'Description' => 'توضیحات',
'Generate' => 'تولید',
'Hover to see from where the permission is inherited.' => 'ماوس را نگه دارید تا ارث بری این مجوز را ببینید.',
'Inherited' => 'ارث برده',
'Invalid authorization item type.' => 'نوع عنصر تصدیق هویت ناصحیح است.',
'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.' => 'درخواست اشتباه است.',
'Modules' => 'ماژول ها',
'Name' => 'نام',
'No authorization items found.' => 'هیچ عنصر تصدیق هویت یافت نشد.',
'No operations found.' => 'هیچ عملی یافت نشد.',
'No relations need to be set for the superuser role.' => 'نقش کاربر ویژه نیاز به تنظیم هیچ گونه رابطه ای نیست.',
'No roles found.' => 'هیچ نقشی یافت نشد.',
'No tasks found.' => 'هیچ تکلیفی یافت نشد.',
'No users found.' => 'هیچ کاربری یافت نشد.',
'Operation' => 'عمل',
'Operations' => 'عمل ها',
'Parents' => 'والدین',
'Permissions' => 'مجوزها',
'Relations' => 'رابطه ها',
'Remove' => 'حذف',
'Revoke' => 'صلب',
'Role' => 'نقش',
'Roles' => 'نقش ها',
'Save' => 'ذخیره',
'Select all' => 'انتخاب همه',
'Select none' => 'عدم انتخاب',
'Super users are always granted access implicitly.' => 'کاربر ویژه به صورت ضمنی دسترسی دارد.',
'Task' => 'تکلیف',
'Tasks' => 'تکلیف ها',
'The requested page does not exist.' => 'صفحه مورد نظر یافت نشد.',
'This item has no children.' => 'این عنصر، هیچ فرزندی ندارد.',
'This item has no parents.' => 'این عنصر هیچ والدینی ندارد.',
'Values within square brackets tell how many children each item has.' => 'مقادیر داخل براکت تعداد فرزندان هر عنصر را نشان می دهد.',
'You are not authorized to perform this action.' => 'شما اجازه انجام این کار را ندارید.',
);
```

## how change my yii app language?

under `config/main.php` add:

```
return array(
...
'language' => 'fa_ir',
...
);
```